# Grouping a list of dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as below:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> itemList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            
itemList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
    { "Item", "001" }, 
    { "Category", "A" }, 
    { "Quantity", 5 } 
});


itemList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
    { "Item", "002" }, 
    { "Category", "B" }, 
    { "Quantity", 8 } 
    });
    
itemList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
    { "Item", "001" }, 
    { "Category", "A" }, 
    { "Quantity", 6 } 
});
```

How would I write my Linq query so that I can get the result as below

```
Output (list of dictionaries):
{ "Item" = "001", "Category" = "A", "Quantity" = 11},
{ "Item" = "002", "Category" = "B", "Quantity" = 8}
```

Comment: I guess the raw data comes from sql or something? If this is the case, I would suggest deserialize the data to object instead of dictionary.

Comment: @LeisenChang Yes, if deserialize it into object, it will become more simple to write linq query. But our system allows user to add new field dynamically without re-compile the code, so dictionary type is the best way I've found (for the time being)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> resultList = itemList
    .Select(d => (Item:d["Item"], Category:d["Category"], Quantity:d["Quantity"]))
    .GroupBy(x => (Item: x.Item, Category: x.Category))
    .Select(g => new Dictionary<string, object> { {"Item",g.Key.Item},{"Category",g.Key.Category},{"Quantity",g.Sum(x => (int)x.Quantity)}})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the dictionary result, though truthfully there should be no dictionaries involved input or output :) Seems likely an upstream questionable design decision

Comment: @TheGeneral: Yes, normally you would use classes instead of dictionaries ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Given**

```
var results = itemList
   .GroupBy(x => new { Item = x["Item"], Category = x["Category"] })
   .Select(x => new
   {
      x.Key.Item,
      x.Key.Category,
      Quantity = x.Sum(y => (int)y["Quantity"])
   });

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{result.Item} {result.Category} {result.Quantity}");
```

**Output**

```
001 A 11
002 B 8
```

Comment: Although the result is not in dictionary format, but this is exactly what i want. Thanks!

Comment: @alexkor1911 nps, good luck